# Yii2: How to stop generating rand() function new value every time record gets updated?

Tags: php, yii2

Im using rand() function to generate `booking_id` in my app, its generating random string while creating the booking record. But when I update the particular record `booking_id` also get updated to some random string. How to stop generating random number while updating the records.

```
<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'booking_id', ['value' => rand('100000',10) ]) ?>
```

Comment: just remove this? `['value' => rand('100000',10) ]`

Comment: nope its not working its still changing the value while updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use behaviors to set the booking id e.g in this example set the `booking_id` with your rand value and this only for the insert event so on update the `booking_id` will be untouched.

Add the behaviors code to your model (or extend your existing behavior with it):

```
namespace app\models\base;  // or whatever your namespace is.
use yii\behaviors\AttributeBehavior; // must be added to the use part to include the correct class.
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Yourclass extends ActiveRecord
{

...


   public function behaviors()
   {
    return [
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['booking_id'],
            ],
            'value' => function ($event) {
                return rand('100000',10);
            },
        ],
    ];
   }

...

}
```

And don't use hidden field from your form. 
The Html Code could be modified so hidden field isn't secure to prevent user modification.

Comment: of course you have to add this to the top of your model (please learn to code) 
`use yii\behaviors\AttributeBehavior;`

but ok i could write the complete path of the yii2 behavior in the line. my mistake.

Comment: `Class 'backend\models\ActiveRecord' not found` getting this error

used `use yii\db\BaseActiveRecord;`

Comment: please post example code you are doing something wrong ;)

Comment: do i need to add something in controller as well?

Comment: ups i guess your generated model code uses `class YourClass extends yii\db\ActiveRecord` my code just extends from `ActiveRecord` and uses 'use yii\db\ActiveRecord;` to include the correct class...

i modified my code.

Comment: ya my code is something like `class YourClass extends yii\db\ActiveRecord`  I have added above code in my controller instead of models